# Stripe Checkout server-side load Customer cards

Tags: stripe-payments

In `Stripe Checkout`, using the **server** integration, is it possible to preload the customer saved cards?

I have a customer with a previous purchase history and I would like to let him pick a saved card details during checkout. 
In the `CRM` I can see that `cus_EyGeAZaPVHwUVg` has the credit card stored (the test one for now, 4242...), but upon a new checkout I am not presented with that, even though the email is filled correctly.

I haven't seen any option in the docs, this is the code:

```
stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: [paymentMethod],
        line_items: [{
            name: name,
            description: description,
            images: [imageUrl],
            amount: amount,
            currency: currency,
            quantity: 1
        }],
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
        customer: 'cus_EyGeAZaPVHwUVg'
    })
```

Comment: It isn't currently possible, but from this, it looks like its on the roadmap https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout#checkout-roadmap --- if the customer already have a save card you might be able to just skip the checkout process altogether and charge the card that's saved.

Comment: @duck thanks for your answer. I hadn't read that :)